# Toggle Saturation of VStacks in ScrollView - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a ScrollView that contains an array of VStacks buttons. The VStack data is filled from a data model named `ProductModel`. I am also passing through an `ObservableObject` from another view which is here: (**NOTE**: This data string does change so it isn't always `All`. Also one of the ProductModels in the ScrollView will match always match the data being passed through).

```
class selectedApplication: ObservableObject {
      @Published var selectedApplication = "All"
}
```

What I am trying to do is grey out all the rows that don't match the passed through data string and only keep the VStack that matches, coloured. After that if a different button is pressed then that VStack becomes coloured and all the others turn/stay grey. I have tried doing this via an `@State` and using a toggle to change the saturation but had no luck. So any direction on how to fix this would be appreciated! Thanks

This is the view with the VStacks:

```
struct ProductTab5View: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var application: selectedApplication
    @State private var selection: Bool? = true
    var product: ProductModel
    
    var body: some View {
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                HStack
                    ForEach(product.application, id: \.self) { item in
                            Button(action: {
                                application.selectedApplication = item
                                selection = false
                            }) {
                                VStack{
                                    Image(item)
                                    Text(item)
                                }
                                .saturation(selection ?? true ? 0.0 : 1.0)
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: As with most things SwiftUI, your problem is that you're using a state variable at the View level inside a loop. Try moving the `@State` variable and all the view code inside for ForEach into their own view. And in general for SwiftUI, _use more views_ (it'll be flattened by iOS itself, so there's no performance loss)

Comment: Okay thank you again! I am still getting my head around SwiftUI but it is good to know about performance, it will definitely make it easier to work with if it is broken down into separate views.

Comment: This is too much spacing. SwiftUI is based on pyramids of doom, so you need to use tighter spacing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for an extra `@State` variable. You can try the following:

```
struct ProductTab5View: View {
    @ObservedObject var application: selectedApplication
    var product: ProductModel

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack
            ForEach(product.application, id: \.self) { item in
                Button(action: {
                    application.selectedApplication = item
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        Image(item)
                        Text(item)
                    }
                    .saturation(application.selectedApplication == item ? 1.0 : 0.1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing and so straight forward. Thank you!